# Milestones and Entitlements

Tags: entitlements, casemilestone

I'm in the process of researching Milestones and Entitlements for my company, and I've come to a few problems.

A) I can't get warning triggers to ha
ppen. The time is set, it's supposed to update a field and it does nothing.

B) If I successfully close the case within the milestone, it does not fire off the field update I have set up with a successful milestone.

And then I have a general question of how to go about implementing Entitlements to an existing org with 10,000+ accounts. Will I really have to create entitlements for each and every existing account?

Answer (score 0):

A is probably some thing you missed.
B you need to trigger auto completion of milestone before closing case
You can create a generic account and configure a common set of entitlements